# mySQL: combine view and stored function with dynamic parameter

Tags: mysql, sql

I've got a View that lists me all my needed information for my web app. The view consists of select statements, joins and some if-else clauses.

Now I would like to get another column in my view with the result of a stored function. But that function has to be called with a parameter as argument. I don't know how I can accomplish that.

My view looks like this:

```
VIEW 'app' AS SELECT 'user'.'user_id' AS 'user_id', 'user'.'name' AS 'name'...
```

This is the query of my function, which depends on the u_id (in this example 103):

```
SELECT IFNULL((
     SELECT !overdue FROM history JOIN status ON history.u_id = status.u_id 
        WHERE history.executed > IFNULL(status.last,0) 
        AND history.u_id = 103 
        ORDER BY history.executed DESC 
     LIMIT 1),0)
```

Currently my views result looks like this:

```
user_id --- name --- created
-------------------------------
103         Peter    2017-02-02
104         Bob      2017-02-01
```

I would like it to have like this, whereas overdue is the result of the function:

```
user_id --- name --- created --- overdue
----------------------------------------
103         Peter    2017-02-02     1
104         Bob      2017-02-01     0
```

I would like to call this function on each 'user_id' in my view and have the result displayed in an additional column (in the view). Thank you for any help.

**EDIT:**

So I just took the query from the function as suggested but it does only show the same value for each u_id. Looks like the IN operator is wrong here.

```
SELECT u_id, IFNULL((
     SELECT !overdue FROM history JOIN status ON history.u_id = status.u_id 
        WHERE history.executed > IFNULL(status.last,0) 
        AND history.u_id IN (select distinct u_id from app) 
        ORDER BY history.executed DESC 
     LIMIT 1),0) from app
```

If I change an entry, every other entry returns the same result. So first I have:

```
u_id --- overdue
103        0
104        0
```

And if I change something from 103, which is processed in the select query:

```
u_id --- overdue
103        1
104        1
```

Both get changed!

**EDIT 2:**

This is my function:

```
begin
declare r int(1); 
SET r= (SELECT IFNULL((SELECT !overdue FROM history JOIN status 
    ON history.u_id = status.u_id 
    WHERE history.executed > IFNULL(status.last,0) 
    AND history.u_id IN (select distinct u_id from app) 
    ORDER BY history.executed DESC 
 LIMIT 1),0));  
return r;
END
```

And I call it from the view like this:

```
if((`overdue_fct`() = 1),'overdue','not overdue') AS 'overdue'
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I believe you can use a `IN` operator and include that condition in your function like

```
SELECT IFNULL((
     SELECT !overdue FROM history JOIN status ON history.u_id = status.u_id 
        WHERE history.executed > IFNULL(status.last,0) 
        AND history.u_id IN (select distinct user_id from app) //this line
        ORDER BY history.executed DESC 
     LIMIT 1),0)
```

Comment: edit: the query does work, but it returns just one value and not for each row. if it's possible, a query which returns me a table with 'u_id' and 'overdue' would be fine, I could use it as additional join in my view.

Comment: @JohnOptional, make your function return a table instead of scalar value

Comment: I did, see my edit. I guess the subquery with the u_id IN SELECT DISTINCT only returns one value for every row.

Comment: @JohnOptional, post your function definition

Comment: Not using function anymore, as it does not have any parameters. Just this query above. If it works I can implement the select query directly into the view without a function, but it's not working yet.

Comment: @JohnOptional, you are running the query on view itself and the select distinct is also happening on same view. You rather get the user_id from the respective table directly

Comment: So what do you suggest? I'll try now to use it directly in the view and see if it does something.

Comment: So I created the function and called it from inside the view. I updated the question, see above.